# Getting iphone screenshots without having an iphone or mac

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot

I need to make an explanatory tutorial for iphone users on how to use my product. The problem is: I don't have an iPhone, nor mac.

I searched the web for some solutions, but none of them allow the change of display language, and they don't show the Cellular connection setting page(e.g. xcode, using macInCloud, online VM services etc.)

Is there some kind of service that offers this as a solution? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cannot display cellular connection on a simulator without a physical device having a cellular connection. You should probably do it in post production, and use icons, description, or on-screen notes and highlights to explain to your user how to use your product.